# How to publish a specific ROS msg using Roslib.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ros

I am following a tutorial to use ROS on a donkey car. Link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLiI_IRedhI

I am attempting to control the car with a React interface by sending ROS messages with roslibjs to a raspberry pi running a rosbridge server. This is how the message looks when I put input in the command line:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rostopic pub /servos_absolute i2cpwm_board/ServoArray "servos:
- servo: 2
  value: 363.0"
```

Here is how I format my roslib message in my react app:

```js
let servoCtrl = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros: ros,
    name: '/servos_absolute',
    messageType: 'i2cpwm_board/ServoArray'
});

let twist = new ROSLIB.Message({
    servos : [
        {servo: 2},
        {value: 363}
    ]
});
```

Here is what I receive from the i2cpwm_board node when sending the messages across rosbridge:

```js
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ rosrun i2cpwm_board i2cpwm_board 
[ INFO] [1579633799.820097186]: I2C bus opened on /dev/i2c-1
[ INFO] [1579633799.835615171]: Setting PWM frequency to 50 Hz
[ERROR] [1579634539.326237522]: Invalid servo number 0 :: servo numbers must be between 1 and 62
```

I am running ROS melodic on my laptop and on my raspberry pi